# Cookies with non-existing paths good for local storage?

Tags: cookies

In RIAs you typically want to maintain some simple state between tabs and reloads but never send it to the server. With IE7 still out there (doesn't support local storage) -- how about cookies with non-existing paths? They will be accessible from JavaScript since they're on the right domain but never sent over the wire unless we do a call using its path.

Are there any caveats?
Such cookies should be possible to set from both the client and server, right?

(I found ppl asking about local storage vs cookies where the main drawback of cookies is they're sent to the server -- "You're wasting bandwidth by sending all the data in each HTTP header." [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies))